# maya python getting and using the result of checkbox

Tags: python, maya

I have a script asking the user to choose an axis of symmetry using checkboxes.  I then wish use that result in another function to create a mirroring tool.  So far, when I try to query the checkbox I keep getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: file  line 81: Object `xAxisBox` not found

I'm a beginner so I apologize if this is obvious, but where am I going wrong?
The relevant code goes as follows:

```
    xAxisBox = cmds.checkBox(l="x")
    yAxisBox = cmds.checkBox(l="y")
    zAxisBox = cmds.checkBox(l="z")
    btAxis=cmds.button( label = "Do the thing!", command = "Blendy();")

    def Blendy ():

    xCheck = cmds.checkBox('xAxisBox', query=True, value = True)
    yCheck = cmds.checkBox('yAxisBox', query=True, value = True)
    zCheck = cmds.checkBox('zAxisBox', query=True, value = True)
    print xCheck
    print yCheck
    print zCheck
```

Comment: It's generally safer and more flexible to pass the command function directly, as a python object, rather than using the string.  This code won't work if you wrap it inside a function.

More details here: http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Maya, so I can't test this for you, but looking at the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19108449/945456), it looks like you need to use the actual python variable without quotes (i.e. `xAxisBox` instead of `'xAxisBox'`), like this:

```
xCheck = cmds.checkBox(xAxisBox, query=True, value = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using cmds you can reference to hardcoded ui names:

```
xAxisBox = cmds.checkBox("xAxisBox", l="x")
yAxisBox = cmds.checkBox("yAxisBox", l="y")
zAxisBox = cmds.checkBox("zAxisBox", l="z")
btAxis = cmds.button(label="Do the thing!", command=Blendy)

def Blendy ():

    xCheck = cmds.checkBox('xAxisBox', query=True, value=True)
    yCheck = cmds.checkBox('yAxisBox', query=True, value=True)
    zCheck = cmds.checkBox('zAxisBox', query=True, value=True)
    print xCheck
    print yCheck
    print zCheck
```

but with pymel you can try this without hardcoding:

```
xAxisBox = pm.checkBox(l="x")
yAxisBox = pm.checkBox(l="y")
zAxisBox = pm.checkBox(l="z")
btAxis = pm.button(
    label="Do the thing!",
    command=pm.Callback(Blendy, 
                        xAxis, yAxis, zAxis)
    )

def Blendy (xbox, ybox, zbox):

    xCheck = cmds.checkBox(str(xbox), query=True, value=True)
    yCheck = cmds.checkBox(str(ybox), query=True, value=True)
    zCheck = cmds.checkBox(str(zbox), query=True, value=True)
    print xCheck
    print yCheck
    print zCheck
```

you can import pymel `import pymel.core as pm`

but if you will use pymel I'd recommend to rewrote Blendy function like:

```
def Blendy(xbox, ybox, zbox):
    print xbox.getValue(), ybox.getValue(), zbox.getValue()
```

and last and not least you can use class for storing values

and answer from neelz from other resource:
using module `partial` the scheme is like with Callback:

```
from functools import partial
cmds.checkBox(onCommand=partial(func_without_parenthesizes, arg, arg))
```

Comment: if you need to pass key arguments to Callback you can do it like so:

ybox = cmds.checkBox(
                     onCommand=pm.Callback(cmds.checkBox, xbox, **{"e":True, "value":True}),
                     offCommand=pm.Callback(cmds.checkBox, xbox, **{"e":True, "value":False})
                    )